# How can Use My own created Java jars in jmeter webdriver sampler?

Tags: java, selenium, jmeter, webdriver

I have some selenium code which repeats in every JMX I have, how can I create a jar of that and use it in JMeter web driver sampler? I am using Beanshell language in web driver sampler.

For example, if I need to use login and logout in every Jmx of web driver sampler, and now I am repeating it in every JMX. How do I keep those login and logout script somewhere and use that. Keeping as jars would be fine, but how can I do it in jMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the .jar containing your functions to perform login/logout will be present in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you should be able to normally using [`import` statement or equivalent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) call your functions from the WebDriver Sampler code.

One point: don't use `java` language as it is not real Java, it is [Beanshell](http://beanshell.org/) interpreter which has limited support of Java features and not very good performance. [Since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use `groovy` for any scripting purposes](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating on next available opportunity. Most likely you won't have to change your code.

---

Also be aware that there is a built-in mechanism in JMeter which helps you to avoid code duplication: [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) so instead of having .jars you can have separate WebDriver Sampler instances which will be doing common tasks like login/logout and you will be able to call them via Module Controller where required.